# Usage of globalize format

Tags: jquery, datetime-format, jquery-globalize

I have confused about globalize format d.

What is the usage of `Globalize.format(new Date(), 'd')`.

it returns the current date with label format as month/date/year..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you list is returning the date using the Standard Date and Time format 'd'.  The 'd', is for short date format.  This page [MSDN Format page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) lists different formats.

Comment: Thanks for u r concern..but u shown as C# it's same for jquery ?

Comment: The formats are based on I believe the ISO 8601 standard.  That is the only page I can find mentioning the short format.  I've been searching, but that is about all I can find.  I've searched for standard date format aliases and my googling abilities are not turning anything else up.

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery globalize regarding DATE:**

Default globalize culture is "English". So we can get the dates in the following format using the jQuery `globalize.format`.

```
Globalize.format(new Date(), 'd'); //Result - 5/23/2016
Globalize.format(new Date(), 'D'); //Result - Monday, May 23, 2016
Globalize.format(new Date(), 'M'); //Result - May 23
```

[**Fiddle Sample**](https://jsfiddle.net/vrbnyxp2/)

We can also format the NUMBER using jQuery globalize. [More information](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-jquerynewpart1/)